# Access the adjacent column value while iterating in python pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a piece of R code which I want to convert to python so while iterating I want to access the adjacent col value in pandas for the current iteration as done in the R code.

Sample data:

```
         2022-10-06  2022-10-11  2022-10-12
0170_QA     -15          30           240
0180_QA      0          480           240
0210_QA      0           0             0
```

Above is the `STO` data-frame converted to matrix in R.

How I want in pandas:

```
If STO[i,j] is negative,
   Yes: Pass the negative value to next time bucket and the pallet matrix.

Example:
======== 
If STO[1,1] = -15 and STO[1,2] = 30
So we will have STO[1,2] =15 and Pallet[1,2] = 0.25
```

```
# Rcode
# m=8 rows and n=17 cols the original dimensions of  STO matrix
for(i in 1:m) {
  for (j in 1:n){       
    if (STO[i,j]<0){
      STO[i,j+1] = STO[i,j+1]+STO[i,j]
      Pallet[i,j+1] =STO[i,j+1]/EachesPerPallet # EachesPerPallet = 60
    }
```

Here `STO` and `Pallet` are matrix and `EachesPerPallet` is int.

I have been able to convert the following dfs to pivot_tables in python.

What I am doing for the looping part:

```
# python code
for index, row in STO.iterrows():
    col = list(STO)
    for i in col:
       if(row[i]<0):
          row[i+1] = row[i+1] + row[i]
          Pallet.loc[index,i+1] = row[i+1] / EachesPerPallet
```

I am getting an error :

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.
```

Can someone help me to solve this error ?

- How do I access the adjacent value of row as I m trying to by doing row[i+1].
- Also is there a more efficient way (vectorization) of doing so ?

Comment: In pandas you wouldn't use `iterrows`, this is inefficient. You should use `shift` to access the next rows/columns **in a vectorial way**.

Comment: @mozway please explain with the help of a snippet.

Comment: what is the full expected output?

Comment: Look at the sample data . If STO[i,j] is negative,
   Yes: Pass the negative value to next time bucket and the pallet matrix.

Example:
======== 
If STO[1,1] = -15 and STO[1,2] = 30
So we will have STO[1,2] =15 and Pallet[1,2] =15/60. #STO[1,2]=15 & EachesperPallet=60.    @mozway